# Callback URL not calling completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, networking, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I’m trying to use ASWebAuthentication to facilitate the authentication process with Oauth 1.0. After the
user enters their credentials and approves my application, oauth provider uses the redirect_url I passed in, com.me.appName:/returnToApp
and the Safari window looks something like this:

[image: Safari Image]

Here's my code:

```
func getAuthTokenWithWebLogin(context: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding) {
      let callbackUrlScheme = “scheme:/returnToApp"
      let authURL = URL(string: Constants.authURL)
     

      guard authURL != nil else{return}
      let webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: authURL!, callbackURLScheme: callbackUrlScheme, completionHandler: { (callBack:URL?, error:Error?) in

          // handle auth response
          guard error == nil, let successURL = callBack else {
              return
          }

          let oauthToken = NSURLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first

          // Do what you now that you've got the token, or use the callBack URL
          print(oauthToken ?? "No OAuth Token")
      })
      
      // New in iOS 13
      webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = context
      // Kick it off
      webAuthSession.start()
  }
```

I don't think it's an issue with ASWebAuthentication, since I've had the same problem when I tried using third party library OauthSwift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad; I didn't realize that the callbackURL must be in myApp:// format, while I had mine as myApp:/ (single slash) thinking this would also work.